# controlling the width of an div with a percentage

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is called 'signup_div' that basically houses 5 input textbooks for the user to input the data. I have the div positioned absolute, with the body of the html page being position relative, so basically the body is the container div. I can't seem to make the width of the  signup div 20% of the page, even when i did it with the input types.

Here is my code:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 1200px;
min-height: 100vh;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#signup_div {
position: absolute;
left: 4%;
top: 7%;
width: 20%;
min-height: 580px;
height: 85%;
min-width: 470px;
background-color: #EBEBEB;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

All of the inputs are positioned relative and have heights and width determined by percentages. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Java tag removed -- I don't see how this question deals with Java programming.

Comment: So why is javascript and jQuery tagged? This is clearly a CSS question. Please don't spam tags.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS for your signup_div includes a `min-width: 470px;` property which is setting the width of your signup_div until such time as 20% is larger than that.

Be careful mixing percentage and pixel widths, there be dragons.

Also, checkout http://jsfiddle.net/ for mocking up examples when you post here. It helps you to isolate the problem, and it helps us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using both width and min-width values.  If you remove the min-width rule, the width with percentage will work.